# ArcGIS online - How do I set-up the feature layer definition to allow me to truncate feature layers via REST API

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

I have written a script to automate the process of refreshing the data in a map in ArcGIS using R.

As part of this I have been attempting to use the ArcGIS online REST API to truncate a feature layer to remove all old data.

The idea I that this will be more efficient than the current method of retrieving all the orgID with the query API and then removing those ids with the deleteFeatures API (which currently works).

```r
  truncateResponse <-
    httr::POST(
      url = paste0(featureLayer, "truncate"),
      body = list(
        f = "json",
        attachmentOnly = "false",
        async = "false",
        token = token
      )
    )

jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(truncateResponse))
```

which returned the following errors
$`error`
$`error`$`code`
[1] 403

$`error`$message
[1] "User does not have permissions to access this service"

$`error`$details
[1] "User does not have permissions to access this service"

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/truncate-feature-layer-.htm

Reading the information above, I have tried to update the feature layer definition using the admin directory.

I have changed "supportsTruncate" to be = true and added "truncate" to "capabilities" from what I can tell sync isn't enabled. However when I change it and update feature layer when i reopen the layer definition these have reverted back.

In summary, how do I set-up the feature layer definition to allow me to truncate feature layers via REST API?

Comment: do you have the right privilege to the featurelayer? You'd probably need read write

Comment: I'm assuming I do seeing as i'm able to use the deleteFeatures and addFeatures API without a problem. is there something i can specifically check to test this?

Comment: from the doc: "Support for the truncate operation only applies if supportsTruncate is true on the layer metadata." Could you check it? You should be able to see it from portal item or server/rest

Comment: So i have tried updating the Layer definition for supportstruncate using the ArcGIS REST Administrator Directory. I think the issue might be that I was trying to update on the feature layer definition. Rather than the FeatureServer, when i try and update supportsTruncate on the featureServer i get the following error -              Invalid definition for 'SourceSchemaChangesAllowed'.
Invalid definition for System.Boolean

Comment: If its not that, I guess my problem is I don't know why the updates to the featureLayer definitions don't remain after i submit them, is it a conflict with something else within the layer or server definitions?

Comment: I believe it should be the layer level. I don't think the server has ' supportsTruncate ' option

Comment: I could not find the supportsTruncate myself, but apparently it's a valid option in publish: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/publish-item.htm